# Kotlin RecyclerView Add Loading footer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a header for my RecyclerView using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksIpDnLiCMs

But I can't figure out how to integrate a loading footer with ProgressBar, I've tried to implement it myself but it's not working, it should load more when I go down but it keeps loading no matter where is my scroll position, and the progressbar won't appear.
Here is my code:

> MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val numberList: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

    var page = 1
    var isLoading = false
    var limit = 10

    lateinit var adapter: RV_Adapter
    lateinit var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        getPage()

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {

                val visibleItemCount = layoutManager.childCount
                val pastVisibleItem = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
                val total = adapter.itemCount

                if(!isLoading) {
                    if((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItem) >= total) {
                        page++
                        getPage()
                    }
                }

                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            }
        })
    }

    fun getPage() {
        isLoading = true
        //progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val start : Int = (page-1)*limit
        val end : Int = page * limit

        for(i in start..end){
            numberList.add("PodView " + i.toString())
        }
        Handler().postDelayed({
            if(::adapter.isInitialized) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            } else {
                adapter = RV_Adapter(this, numberList)
                recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            }
            isLoading = false
            //progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }, 0)

    }
}
```

> RV_Adapter.kt

```
class RV_Adapter(private val context: Context, private val numberList: MutableList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder<*>>() {

    companion object {
        private const val TYPE_HEADER = 0
        private const val TYPE_ITEMS = 1
        private const val TYPE_FOOTER = 2
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder<*> {

        return when(viewType) {
            TYPE_HEADER -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rv_header, parent, false)
                HeaderViewHolder(view)
            }

            TYPE_ITEMS -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false)
                ItemViewHolder(view)
            }

            TYPE_FOOTER -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rv_footer, parent, false)
                FooterViewHolder(view)
            }

            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid View Type")
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return numberList.size + 1
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder<*>, position: Int) {
        if(holder is ItemViewHolder){
            holder.numberBarText.text = numberList[position]
        }
        if(holder is HeaderViewHolder){
            holder.cardView.radius = 50f
        }


    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        if(position == 0) {
            return TYPE_HEADER
        }

        return TYPE_ITEMS
    }

    inner class HeaderViewHolder(itemView: View): BaseViewHolder<View>(itemView) {
        val cardView : CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileImageCardView)

        override fun bind(item: View) {}

    }

    inner class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View): BaseViewHolder<View>(itemView) {
        val numberBarText = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.numberBarText)

        override fun bind(item: View) {}

    }
    inner class FooterViewHolder(itemView: View): BaseViewHolder<View>(itemView) {

        override fun bind(item: View) {}

    }
}
```

> **UPDATE:**

After combining my RecyclerView with BottomNavigationView, the footer and header are glitching. A more solid solution is required rather than adding strings to the arraylist like: `numberList.add("VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a footer item in your Adapter your should implement a few things inside your code.

First thing is that you should create a new `itemViewType` for your footer.
The second thing which you have to do is to create a way that you tell your `Adapter` that this view is actually a footer. Since you are using `List` with `String` you should add something like this at the end of the `List`:

```
numberList.add("VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER")
```

and after that:

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
      val item = numberList[position]
      if(position == 0) {
          return TYPE_HEADER
      } else if(item == "VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER") {
          return TYPE_FOOTER
      }
      return TYPE_ITEMS
}
```

And you should check for lastVisibleItem, not the firstVisible one and get the nextPage after that.
Keep in mind that after getting the next page you will have to remove the latest item from the `List` which will be your footer view, add the next page to the `List` and then decide if you will need to add a new footer.

Hope this helps you to understand how to make it work in your situation.

Comment: This trick worked for me, but after I combined my RecyclerView with Bottom Navigation everything went crazy bad. So unfortunately this technique isn't efficient for me.

Comment: You should add more detail what is the problem and what are you doing so we can help. My answer was more an basic idea than a real implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider maintaining the isLoading variable also inside the adapter and (un)setting it from your MainActivity by adding the following method in your adapter:

```
var isLoading:Boolean
fun setIsLoading(value:Boolean) {
    isLoading = value
}
```

Then you could change the methods like so:

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return numberList.size + 1
}
```

TO

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return if(!isLoading) isnumberList.size + 1 else isnumberList.size + 2 
}
```

and

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    if(position == 0) {
        return TYPE_HEADER
    }

    return TYPE_ITEMS
}
```

TO

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    if(position == 0) {
        return TYPE_HEADER
    } else if(position == isnumberList.size + 2) {
        return TYPE_FOOTER
    }

    return TYPE_ITEMS
}
```

Comment: Nice. Now my list is loading when I reach the buttom but the footer progress bar isn't showing

Comment: Try to call notifyDatasetChanged() on the adapter when you load from the MainActivity inside the getPage() method

Comment: I already call notifyDatasetChanged() inside getPage() as you can see in my code

Comment: If you share your codebase, I could try to help further.

Comment: After some trial and error I can see the footer when I scroll to the bottom. but I don't understand exacly how is it working.
I am posting and Update in the question with the updated functions